# Shrinking a git Repository forgeting history keeping 3 branches

Tags: git, gitlab

I have

- a big git repo with too big .git (~600Mo) folder.
- I made a gitlab read only archive of it
- I want to start from the actual working copy a new repo.

but ...

- I need to keep master + 2 branches.

What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

From your concern, I guess you have too many branches that have unnecessary legacy changes which is increasing the repo size.

I suggest you to bulk remove all the branches except from the 2 branches you want to keep. This should reduce the size considerably.

Follow these steps for new repository (if you really want to):

1. Now you have 3 branches with you including the master. Switch to master and copy all the files. Create a new repository by copying all these files to that repository.
2. Commit the files and push your master branch.
3. Switch to branch1 of your old repo and copy all the files.
4. Create a new branch1 on your new repo from master.
5. Paste all the files copied from old repository into the new repo now.
6. Commit all these changes and push the new branch1 to new repository.
7. Follow similar steps for branch2.

Comment: The size is not due to too many branches but to big files on old state of master so the "remove old history" is needed too

Comment: Then my new-repo suggestion should work for you I guess